# Configuring and Testing Freeradius on debian

Tags: linux, debian, networking, radius

I'm trying to set up a freeradius server on debian (LTS kernel 3.2.0.4amd64; Wheezy 7.10) it seems to want to use freeradius version 2.1.12

Installing the package wasn't a big deal (**apt-get install freeradius**) and I've tried following some guides for configuring it but none of my tested configurations worked, and I couldn't figure out how to test if the server was even working to begin with in my console. I saw some guides using commands to test the server from the host but these commands weren't available on my system...

I did my best to try and follow [this guide](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/8021X-HOWTO/freeradius.html) and also tried digging through the [official how-to](http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/HOWTO) but I simply couldn't figure out why things weren't working...

I'm trying to set it up for my wireless router's WPA2-Enterprise wlan security option. It is configured thusly:

[image: Asus Config]

(I know the port is not the default, I did not forget to configure this in the settings files of course)

So, how am I supposed to do this? I need to be able to connect from Windows and Linux clients.

ifconfig:

```
root@VAULT:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:c0:43:54
          inet addr:192.168.1.62  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14879878 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11963411 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:15827735362 (14.7 GiB)  TX bytes:13994998174 (13.0 GiB)
          Interrupt:43

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12570 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12570 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1558356 (1.4 MiB)  TX bytes:1558356 (1.4 MiB)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: @GAD3R updated post.